# mysql query does not respect the date parameter

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query as follow:

```sql
SELECT   ch.id, ch.checkname, MAX(ch.CheckDate) AS CheckDate, 
         ch.SeverityNumber, md.CheckRef1, md.CheckSubject, 
         DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME( ch.CheckDate),CURDATE()) AS dateFromalarm 
FROM     checks ch, model md 
WHERE    ch.SysName='MV3R' 
AND      ch.environment='Z/OS' 
AND      md.CheckName=ch.CheckName 
AND      ***ch.CheckDate <=1569785343*** 
GROUP BY CheckName 
ORDER BY ch.CheckName DESC;
```

This query supposed to return one row for each checkname that has the latest checkdate.
checkname is not unique and there are many rows for each checkname in the table.
The problem is that when i change the number in the bolded section (***ch.CheckDate <=1569785343***) it does NOT change the result at all..
any ideas?

Comment: checkDate might be `Date` or `Datetime` or `timestamp` type variable, so you cannot just directly check the date as comparing a integer to date.
try something like ch.checkDate <= '2019-02-01';

Comment: my CheckDate field is an a number (unixdatetime) so i can compare it.

Answer (score 0):

lets try to isolate your `max(checkdate)` to avoid grouping multiple columns, i believe you only have 1 info for each `checkname`.

```
select ch.id
    , ch.checkname
    , t1.CheckDate
    , ch.SeverityNumber
    , md.CheckRef1
    , md.CheckSubject
    , datediff(from_unixtime(ch.CheckDate),CURDATE()) as dateFromalarm 
from 
    (select checkname, max(CheckDate)as CheckDate from checks where CheckDate <=1569785343 group by checkname) as t1
join checks ch on ch.checkname = t1.checkname
join model md on md.CheckName=ch.CheckName
where ch.SysName='MV3R' 
    and ch.environment='Z/OS'    
order by ch.CheckName desc;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but what i need is to get one row for each checkname where the date is the heist in that group. so i believe i need to add a group by checkname at the end of the query before the order by.